# How to locate the textbox using selenium-webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

here's the code of the textbox :

```
<form>
    <input autocomplete="off" id="number" name="number" type="tel" aria-describedby="error-for-number tooltip-for-number" data-current-field="number" data-fillr-id="424069765" data-fillr="bound" style="padding: 8px 10px; font-size: 14px; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;San Francisco&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, sans-serif;">
</form>
```

By the way it did't work when I tried to access it by id or name like this :

```
browser.find_element_by_id('number')
browser.find_element_by_name('number')
```

Comment: If you don't want to know the type of the element then how are you going to decide whether it is a button or text-box?

Comment: you should do a common mapping with a selector that gets both of these elements, then try a element.Clear() to check if its an input (textbox), if it is not, an exception will be returned.
You can catch that exception and click the element instead,and if clear does not throw an exception, just type the text you want.

Comment: what error does it show when you try to find it by id?

Answer (score 0):

To locate the *TextBox* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#number[name='number'][type='tel']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='number' and @name='number'][@type='tel']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```